# Unable to delete question

Tags: support

I'm trying to get this question deleted https://stackoverflow.com/questions/24117203/qbxml-iteminventoryadd-returns-xml-error

I'm no longer working on the project and won't be testing any answers, so I can't accept one.

None of the current "answers" have any upvotes and an answer has not been accepted, so why can't I delete it?

I tried before, and failed, so I attempted to flag it for a mod to delete, but it was declined with the reason as "You can delete your own questions if they don't have upvoted or accepted answers.".

This didn't seem to be true. So I just added my own answer (if you read it, you'll see it definitely is not an answer to the question) and accepted it. Then I read a post here on meta about a similar thing and it said I should be able to delete it. So I unaccepted my answer and flagged it again. This time the decline reason was "a moderator reviewed your flag, but found no evidence to support it".

So what am I supposed to do with this?  I don't want to leave it hanging and I don't think I should be accepting my own "i've given up on this" answer...

Comment: Uh, the question you linked was deleted a half hour ago by @GeorgeStocker.  Refresh your browser.

Comment: *Question not found. Have you tried restarting your machine?*

Comment: It actually *was* deleted. Regardless; IIRC you can't self-delete if there are 3 or more answers; in addition to the upvote rule.

Comment: @BradleyDotNET "Users can delete their own questions if the question: ...only one answer, but that answer has no upvotes" Nope, if there are 2 or more.

Comment: @Kendra I stand corrected; the limit was at 2, not 3

Comment: Ah that would explain it!

Answer (score 22, accepted):

I declined your flag before I really sat down and studied the question.  After further reflection, I went ahead and deleted it.

I'm sorry about the decline.

Comment: Ahh understood, thanks. I should have F5'd when I got back to the desk!

Answer (score -7):

Open your question.. You have following option. one is delete :)
share edit close delete flag